# How to configure Apache Wicket with Spring 4 Java based configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, wicket

I have a Spring MVC project up and running. It only has REST APIs and do not have any view.
I want to use Apache Wicket as the view part, which can use the `@Service` annotated classes.

I don't exactly how and where to start.

**P.S.** I have pure Java based configuration for Spring MVC, meaning there is no web.xml file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just add a custom WicketFilter to your application like:

```
@Component
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*")
public class MyWicketFilter extends WicketFilter {

    public MyWicketFilter() {
        super(new MyWicketApplication());
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the the Spring config class right? And how can I run this app now? No more configurations?

Comment: No this is just an additional bean in your Application. I assumed that your application is already running and you wanted to add Wicket to it. You'll need to make sure that Spring picks this class up during startup (@ComponentScan, @Bean in your SpringConfig, etc)

Comment: Yes my Spring app is up and running, I need to add Wicket. So you are saying the wicket dependency and the above code, that it?

Comment: Correct. Wicket will pick up any requests that go through the WicketFilter. The code above is in my opinion the easiest way to achieve that. (It's pretty much the equivalent to adding the WicketFilter to the web.xml)

Comment: `[org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] -> [refresh()] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.config.Config$MyWicketFilter': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.config.Config$MyWicketFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.config.Config$MyWicketFilter.<init>()`

Comment: Actually, it's update and running now Thanks :), but how to hit the Wicket Home Page?

Comment: Actually, I was hitting the wrong URL, it did work, really really Thanks :)

Comment: How can I use @Autowired annotations in the Wicket Pages?

Comment: You can use @SpringBean, see: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Spring#Spring-Annotation-basedApproach

Comment: Thank you very very much once again, you just made my 2 days worth of Googling :)